# golang - how to split string in template

Tags: go

I try to use template.FuncMap but there are panic error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

code:

```
type Article struct{
    Id int
    Title string
    Tags  string
}

var (
    tplFuncMap template.FuncMap 
)

func main() {
    article := &Article{Id:1, Title:"hello world", Tags:"golang,javascript"}
    tplFuncMap =  make(template.FuncMap)
    tplFuncMap["Split"] = Split
    tpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("a.html", "b.html")
    tpl = tpl.Funcs(tplFuncMap)
    tpl.Execute(os.Stdout, article)
}

func Split(s string, d string) []string {
    arr := strings.Split(s, d)
    return arr
}
```

a.html

```
//i want to split tags and range
{{$arr := Split .Tags ","}}
{{range $k, $v := $arr}}
    <a href="{{$v}}">{{$v}}</a>
{{end}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ignoring the error returned by `template.ParseFiles`, that will probably tell you your problem. ParseFiles is probably throwing an error because the function `Split` isn't defined when you parse the template. Never ignore errors.

**Edit**

To make it work, do something like this:

```
tplFuncMap =  make(template.FuncMap)  
tplFuncMap["Split"] = Split  
tmpl, err = template.New("").Funcs(tplFuncMap).ParseFiles("a.html", "b.html")
```

The difference is that the `FuncMap` is defined before the templates are parsed.

Comment: You missed the important bit (the reason for the error): accessing `Funcs` on `tpl` which is `nil`.

Comment: @Tyler Egeto, In real code i have output error. i am sure there are something worng in "a.html" Split function, because if i comment the code it's work well.

Comment: The reason it works when you remove the Split function in the template is because the parser is no longer finding an undefined Func. As nemo mentioned, I could have been more clear. I'm updating with an example.